# Store int32_t in an NSDictionary

Tags: cocoa, numbers, boxing

How can I store a variable of type `int32_t` (e.g. for ABPropertyID) in an `NSDictionary`?

`[NSNumber numberWithInt:...]` doesn't seem to work.

Thanks

---

From the comments:

```
NSLog(@" %@ %@ ", [NSNumber numberWithLong:kABPersonFirstNameProperty], kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```

Prints: 0 (null) Any ideas?

Comment: How is `NSNumber` not working for you? It's exactly the right thing to use.

Comment: NSLog(@" %@ %@ ", [NSNumber numberWithLong:kABPersonFirstNameProperty], kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

Prints: 0 (null) 

Any ideas?

Comment: Dave: That is the correct output. In the second formatter, you passed `kABPersonFirstNameProperty` (an integer name), which is currently defined as zero, where you told `NSLog` you would give it an object pointer. It printed zero as an object pointer, which is `NULL`, which shows up in the output as “(null)”. The first formatter also takes an object, and you gave it one: An NSNumber object whose value is zero (`kABPersonFirstNameProperty`). What appears in the output is the description of that object, which is “0”.

Comment: So, the code is working fine, exactly as you intended. You're just reading it incorrectly.

Comment: (Actually, not quite fine. If you pass some other name in the second place, you'll crash, because you're still trying to print an integer [`kAB…Property`] as an object [`%@`]. See http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265 for the list of format specifiers, so you can see which one is correct.)

Answer (score 2):

`+[NSNumber numberWithInteger:]` will hold a 32-bit number nicely on all 32-bit and 64-bit systems. `+[NSNumber integerValue]` will retrieve it. If you need it unsigned you can use ``+[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:]`.

Comment: While what you say is true, I think in this context it's quite misleading, because: A) the same is true for the `numberWithInt:` method used in the question (holding a 32-bit number nicely on all 32-bit and 64-bit systems), and B) @Dave's problem is obviously elsewhere.

Comment: `numberWithInt:` will produce a negative number for some 32-bit values while `numberWithInteger:' will not. I thought that was his problem because I answered before he fleshed his question out.

Answer (score 2):

I assume here that Dave's issue is specific to the kAB... constants--I may be mistaken in which case ignore the following :)

I believe that the issue here is not that you are using incorrect syntax; it's an order-of-initialization problem.  I'm guessing that you are attempting this operation before having initialized the kAB... constants -- e.g., by calling `ABAddressBookCreate()`.  Somewhat confusing the issue is the snippet:

`NSLog(@" %@ %@ ", [NSNumber numberWithLong:kABPersonFirstNameProperty], kABPersonFirstNameProperty);`

which should be:

`NSLog(@" %@ %d ", [NSNumber numberWithLong:kABPersonFirstNameProperty], kABPersonFirstNameProperty);`

Here's my output -- prior to calling `ABAddressBookCreate()`:

`NSLog(@"Check: %d %d %d", kABPersonFirstNameProperty,kABPersonMiddleNameProperty,kABPersonLastNameProperty);`

produces

> Check: 0 0 0

after the call, the same log statement produces

> Check: 0 6 1

Comment: All my constants started returning zero when I compiled my previously working (i.e. non-zero constants) code against iOS 6. The fix is to call `ABAddressBookCreate()` before using any ABAddressBook `kABPerson*` "constants" as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else has said, `NSNumber` will work for this. However, there are two other options you should be at least vaguely aware of: `CFDictionary` (the same thing as `NSDictionary` under the hood, but it lets you store arbitrary pointers or pointer-sized integers) and `NSMapTable`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, using NSNumber seems like the best idea.

For harder cases, you can always use NSValue or NSData to put any type or pointer into a Objective-C object that can be stored in Cocoa collections.

```
int32_t myInt = 42;
NSValue *myValue = [NSValue value:&myInt withObjCType:@encode(int32_t)];
```

- [Number and Value Programming Topics for Cocoa: Using Values](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Values.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000174-BAJJHDEG)
- [NSValue Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000177-BCIFHDEF)